# Filtering data using two columns in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have files that are versioned, using a major and minor version.
Now what I want to do is grab the highest major versions of all the files (which I've done already). Then check minor versions to see if it contains a 0. If it does throw out that whole set of versions. So for instance. My first query returns:

```
FileA Ver 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 
FileB Ver 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4 
FileC Ver 5.1, 5.2, 5.3.
```

So in all 11 rows/records. Now my second query should take that result and throw out all of the FileA versions because one of the versions has a 0 as a minor version. So the second query should return:

```
FileB Ver 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4 
FileC Ver 5.1, 5.2, 5.3.
```

7 rows/records in all.
Could anyone help me with this query?  I'm using SQL server 2008 if that helps.

```
latestFileMajorVersion(fileId, majRev)
as
(
    --Gets files with highest major version
    select distinct v_fileid, max(v_majrev)
    from files
    group by v_fileid
),
latestFileVersions(fileId, majRev, minRev)
as
(
    --Gets files with highest major version and all minor versions
    select fileId, majRev, minrev
    from files
    inner join latestFileMajorVersion on files.v_fileid = latestFileMajorVersion.fileId
    where v_majrev = latestFileMajorVersion.majRev
),
latestFileVersion(fileId, majRev, minRev)
as
(
    select fileId, majRev, minrev
    from latestFileVersions
    where --I'm stuck here.
)
select v_fileid, v_majrev, v_minrev, v_status
from files
inner join latestFileVersion on v_fileid = latestFileVersion.fileId
where latestFileVersion.majRev = v_majrev and latestFileVersion.minRev = v_minrev and v_status = 'UnAssigned'
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Files](
    [v_fileid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [v_libid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [v_userid] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [v_majrev] [int] NOT NULL,
    [v_minrev] [int] NOT NULL,
    [v_status] [nvarchar](16) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Files] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [v_fileid] ASC,
    [v_majrev] ASC,
    [v_minrev] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_Files] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [v_majrev] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [IX_Files] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [v_minrev] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: what does the table look like? Are MajorVersion and MinorVersion separate columns?

Comment: Query is coming in a minute. And yes, MajorVersion and MinorVersion are in separate columns.

Comment: This is what I have so far in the query.

Comment: Can we also get definition of tables if possible?

Comment: How do I give the green checkmark to two or more users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working solution with a little example table you can play with.  Execute it exactly as it is with no other sql around it.  You can then modify it to suit your need.

```
declare @files table (fileId int identity(1,1), majRev int, minRev int)
insert into @files values (1,0)
insert into @files values (1,1)
insert into @files values (2,0)
insert into @files values (2,2)
insert into @files values (3,1)
insert into @files values (3,2)
insert into @files values (4,1)

 select fileId, majRev, minRev
   from @files f
  where not exists 
        (select *
           from @files
          where minRev = 0
            and majRev = f.majRev
            and fileId = f.fileId)
```

Comment: the first query gave me results whereas the second query produced no rows.

Comment: I've edited to leave only one query so it's simpler to understand.  Please let us know if this solved your problem.  If it did not, then let us know why and what else you need.

Comment: A combination of the two queries actually give the results I want.

Comment: select *
from Files as fa
where not exists 
(select 1
 from Files where v_minrev = 0 and v_majrev = fa.v_majrev and  fa.v_fileid = v_fileid)

Comment: You don't have the f.fileid = fileid in your example. t-clausen.dk did.

Comment: ah, good point.  i took back my comment and edited the query for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your query using this idea for the syntax. It works for the sample data you provided.

```
declare @t table (fileid varchar(10), [version] varchar(5))

insert @t values('FileA','1.0')
insert @t values('FileA','1.1')
insert @t values('FileA','1.2')
insert @t values('FileA','1.3')
insert @t values('FileB','2.1')
insert @t values('FileB','2.2')
insert @t values('FileB','2.3')
insert @t values('FileB','2.4')
insert @t values('FileC','5.1')
insert @t values('FileC','5.2')
insert @t values('FileC','5.3')

SELECT * FROM @t t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM @t WHERE PARSENAME([version], 1) = '0' AND t.fileid = fileid)
```

Comment: A combination of the two queries actually give the result I want.

Comment: select *
from Files as fa
where not exists 
(select 1
 from Files where v_minrev = 0 and v_majrev = fa.v_majrev and  fa.v_fileid = v_fileid)

Comment: yes, I was a bit lazy, but it seemed you had already done most of the work and only needed this part

Answer (score 0):

When I try to code something, sometimes I get too caught up with making an "elegant" solution, as opposed to just brute-forcing the solution and having it apply only to a particular problem.

So I'm wondering if 1) I've brute-forced this solution and 2) is there a more "elegant" or clever way to go about writing this. All comments, critiques, and/or suggestions are welcome.

```
;with solution(fileId, majrev, minrev, status, checkid, maxrev) 
as
(
select *
from files
inner join
(
    select v_fileid, MAX(v_majrev) as max_major
    from files
    group by v_fileid
) as max_versions on max_versions.v_fileid = files.v_fileid and 
                     max_major = files.v_majrev
except                   
select *
from files
inner join
(
    select v_fileid, MAX(v_majrev) as max_major
    from files
    where v_minrev = 0
    group by v_fileid
) as unwanted_versions on unwanted_versions.v_fileid = files.v_fileid and 
                          max_major = files.v_majrev
)
select *
from solution
```

Comment: It seems t-clausen.dk and Milimetric answers are the more clever/elegant solution.